# convert named list with mixed content to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a better and nicer way to convert named list with mixed content to data frame?

The working example:

```
my_list <- list("a" = 1.0, "b" = "foo", "c" = TRUE)

my_df <- data.frame(
  "key" = names(my_list),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

my_df[["value"]] <- unname(my_list)
```

Is it possible to do this conversion in one step?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can use `stack` from `base R`

```
stack(my_list)
```

According to `?stack`

> The stack function is used to transform data available as separate columns in a data frame or list into a single column that can be used in an analysis of variance model or other linear model. The unstack function reverses this operation.

---

Or with `enframe`

```
library(tidyverse)
enframe(my_list) %>% # creates the 'value' as a `list` column
   mutate(value = map(value, as.character)) %>% # change to single type
   unnest
```

Comment: Hi @akun, `stack` is simple and quick but I don't find the help document. Would you like to add the package name (base?) or explain it a little bit?

Comment: @Jiaxiang  it is from `base R`.  According to `?stack` `The stack function is used to transform data available as separate columns in a data frame or list into a single column that can be used in an analysis of variance model or other linear model. The unstack function reverses this operation.`.  Here, it is a named list.  So, it unlist the values and at the same time, replicate the names of the list as a separate column

Comment: @akrun if I understand correctly, `stack` solution needs another step with `colnames` to change names of columns to **key** and **value**? There is no other trick to do this in one operation?

Comment: @RSzT  You can use `setNames(stack(my_list)[2:1], c("key", "value"))` as the default columns are named with 'ind' and 'values' where as in`enframe` there is an option to change the name in the argument

Comment: @akrun It seems that `ind` column (or `key` after above) is a factor.

Comment: @RSzT  By default, the 'key' column will be  a `factor` returned from `stack`.  If the output type is needed as character then need to transform `transform(setNames(stack(my_list)[2:1], c("key", "value")), key = as.character(key))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::as_tibble` to coerce the list into a data frame / tibble. This will automatically create a data frame where the list's names are column names, and the list items correspond to rows.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_list <- list("a" = 1.0, "b" = "foo", "c" = TRUE)

as_tibble(my_list)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>       a b     c    
#>   <dbl> <chr> <lgl>
#> 1     1 foo   TRUE
```

To reshape into the two-column format you have, pipe it into `tidyr::gather`, where the default column names are key and value. Because of the different data types in the column `value`, this will coerce all the values to character.

```r
as_tibble(my_list) %>%
  gather()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   key   value
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     1    
#> 2 b     foo  
#> 3 c     TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>